# Comprehension in order

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a task and there is no way to contact the customer.
the task is:
"You need to download the page https://nameOfTheSide through a browser or program (the site name was removed just in case) and in the saved copy change the part of this page under the logo, starting with the element with the “collection-title” class according to the design from Figma. Price block and everything below it, as well as the products on the page, do not need to be changed."

The problem now is that when you download the site, the data is already compiled, but it’s a little difficult to work with and I don’t have access to the site structure and the customer also didn’t put the link to gid.

How can I work with that? Are there any kind of ways to download pages with their structure? Is it ok that taksk is given in that way?

I am still new to this area and therefore maybe I don’t understand something, so please tell me.